# Pandas DataFrame styled for presentation

Tags: pandas, numpy, seaborn

In Pandas and Seaborn we can create beautiful graphical displays. However sometimes the best thing to show are numbers, for example in a data frame or pivot table.

Are there tools available to generate a similarly attractive display of numbers? (Yes, I suppose I can export to word or excel but that would have been true for beautiful graphs too...)

Comment: One option would be to use `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` and apply your own custom styling to the output with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on your definition of attractive, but one can make simple clean looking tables from `pandas` using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()` function. Combine this with custom CSS, or Bootstrap CSS as below, and the results are decent.

```
import pandas as pd

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Column B': [5,4,3,2,1], 'Column C': [100,200,300,400,500]})

with open('test_table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(sample_df.to_html())
```

Then simply edit the output html with some CSS, in this case Bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Column A</th>
                                <th>Column B</th>
                                <th>Column C</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>0</th>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>100</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>1</th>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>200</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>2</th>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>300</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>3</th>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>400</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>4</th>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>500</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Resulting in something simple looking like this:

[image: bootstrap table example]

Which could be saved to PDF etc.